# How use two Dashboard Stripe Accounts

Tags: stripe-payments

Currently, I working with Stripe gateway service. In my integration use only one Dashboard Stripe Account (one Publishable key + Secret key). I intend that my system create charges in two different Dashboard Stripe Account, depending others conditions.

I have analysed the "Connected accounts" using only one Dashboard Stripe Account, but is not useful for me. I intend that each billing company have their Dashboard Stripe Account access (without mistake).

Is there any alternative beyond create customers / payment methods in both Dashboard Stripe Accounts?

Screenshot #1:

[image]

Screenshot #2:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can build your application to manage two separate sets of keys based on the business logic for when to use one account or the other, but outside of Connect there is no other native support for something like this from Stripe. But you can absolutely do it manually. Yes, you would need to create any customers in both accounts, but this is true in a platform-connected account arrangement, too.

Comment: The issue on dealing with multiple accounts is if we got 3D-Secure validation, the customer will be asked to validate his card as many times as accounts we have (not to mention the time it takes to register)... We were trying to find a simple solution for that.

Comment: It sounds like you likely want to set up an org level platform account with your various sub-accounts set up as connected accounts. If you do this, you can save payment methods on the platform account and clone the payment methods to the connected accounts: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-methods/connect#cloning-payment-methods

Comment: Yes, I understand. It's problem is what I said in the main topic: "I intend that each billing company have their Dashboard Stripe Account access". I checked that "Connected accounts" have an button "View Dashboard as Connected account" that allows to see the operations / costumers in the connected account. It's possivel give permissions for an email that have access a one dasboard of one connected account?

Comment: See here for sharing access to accounts: https://stripe.com/docs/dashboard/teams

Comment: There is no option to grant permissions to the one Connected Account Dashboard on  link (the link is only for Stripe account not Connected Account). When I say "Connected Account Dashboard" I mean the one obtained through the button "View Dashboard as Connected account" (see pic1 and pic2 on main topic). Do you know this option? Is it not possible to grant permission just to access this dashboard?

Comment: What type of accounts are these? This is only possible with Standard accounts with full dashboard access -- you would log into that account directly (not via the platform) and share access there. If you talking about eg custom accounts, they don't have dashboard access so then no this would not be possible as you describe.

Comment: Yes, I used the custom accounts. I will check the Standard account. Thank you.